# Redirect 2 folders from https to http on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, http, https

My WordPress hosted website is in https, but I want to remove https for two folders as I need to run http pages inside that pages using iframe. I have tried editing in `.htacess` file, but nothing worked.

I have tried using PHP code too, nothing worked.

Here is my `.htacess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c><br>
RewriteEngine On<br>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off<br>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]<br>
</IfModule><br>
SetEnv PHPRC /home/mysitename/public_html/php.ini<br>
# BEGIN WordPress<br>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c><br>
RewriteEngine On<br>
RewriteBase /<br>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d<br>
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]<br><br>
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Your file is misnamed, it should be `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# This entry meant for .htaccess file
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off          [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} /  [NC]
RewriteRule   ^    https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [L]
# RewriteRule (.*) /folder/path [L]
```

Comment: Would you explain (by editing the answer) what this does and how it answers the question?